# Java8 - Mapping with Streams without Collecting for Performance

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

### Exponentially Growing Stream

I have a `Stream` that grows **exponentially** for creating permutations. So each call to `addWeeks` increases the number of elements in the `Stream`.

```
Stream<SeasonBuilder> sbStream = sbSet.stream();

for (int i = 1; i <= someCutOff; i++) {
    sbStream = sbStream.map(sb -> sb.addWeeks(possibleWeeks))
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream); 
}

// Collect SeasonBuilders into a Set
return sbStream.collect(Collectors.toSet());   // size > 750 000
```

### Problems

- Each call to `addWeeks` returns a `Set<SeasonBuilder>` and collecting everything into a `Set` takes a while.
- `addWeeks` is not static and needs to be called on each `SeasonBuilder` in the stream, each time through the loop

  ```
  public Set<SeasonBuilder> addWeeks(
      final Set<Set<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>>> possibleWeeks) {
          return possibleWeeks.stream()
                  .filter(containsMatchup())   // Finds the weeks to add
                  .map(this::addWeek)   // Create new SeasonBuilders with the new week
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  ```
- Out of memory error..... when possible weeks has size = 15

### Questions

- Should I be using a method chain other than **`map`** followed by **`flatmap`**?
- How can I modify `addWeeks` so that I don't have to collect everything into a `Set`?

  - Should I return a `Stream<SeasonBuilder>`? Can I `flatmap` a `Stream`?

## Update:

Thanks for the help everyone!

I have put the code for the methods in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexdriedger/5960333b1fb516bde3351200c41df11e)

Thanks to @Holger and @lexicore for suggesting returning a `Stream<SeasonBuilder>` in `addWeeks`. Minor performance increase, as was predicted by @lexicore

I tried using `parallelStream()` and there was no significant change in  performance

### Context

I am creating all possible permutations of a [Fantasy Football](http://www.fantasy.nfl.com) season, which will be used elsewhere for stats analysis. In a 4-team, 14-week season, for any given week, there could be three different possibilities

- (1 vs 2) , (3 vs 4)
- (1 vs 3) , (2 vs 4)
- (1 vs 4) , (2 vs 3)

To solve the problem, plug in the permutations, and we have all our possible seasons. Done! But wait... what if Team 1 only ever plays Team 2. Then the other teams would be sad. So there are some constraints on the permutations.

Every team must play each other roughly the same amount of times (i.e. Team 1 cannot play against Team 3 ten times in a single season). In this example - 4-teams, 14 weeks - each team is capped at playing another team 5 times. So some sort of filtering has to happen when creating permutations, to avoid non-valid seasons.

Where this gets more interesting is:

- 6 Team League  --  15 possible weeks
- 8 Team League  --  105 possible weeks
- 10 Team League  --  945 possible weeks

I am trying to optimize performance where possible, because there are a lot of permutations to create. A 4-team, 14-week season creates 756 756 (=14!/(5!5!4!)) possible seasons, given the constraints. 6-team or 8-team seasons just get crazier.

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? If you want a thing that is fast, generating all permutations is very likely not the best approach to begin with.

Comment: Isn’t it obvious, how you have to change `addWeeks`? Let it return a `Stream` of elements instead of a `Set` (and change the name to something that reflects what it actually does, as it obviously does not `add…`). Unless, you want to redesign everything, including the things you have not mentioned in your question, that’s the only possible change. Whether you use `map`, followed by `flatMap` or a single `flatMap`, is irrelevant.

Comment: @alexdriedger collecting any *> 750_000 elements* to any data structure is going to be slow + adding the permutations makes things only worse. Holger is right unless you explain in simple words what you want to try to achieve it's hard to give any advice.

Comment: @Holger would you mind making that an answer?

Comment: I think that it would be a good boost to activate parallel stream when you instansiate your SeasonBuilder stream. Try it and give me feedback.

Comment: @Eugene Updated the post with some context!

Comment: @GKanellis I tested it with `parallelStream() ` and it didn't improve performance :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your whole construction is very suspicious to begin with. If you're interested in performance it is unlikely that generating all permutations explicitly is a good approach.

I also don't believe that collecting to set and streaming again is *the* performance problem.

But nevertheless, to answer your question: why don't you return `Stream<SeasonBuilder>` from `addWeeks` directly, why do you collect it to set first? Return the stream directy, without collecting:

```
public Stream<SeasonBuilder> addWeeks(
    final Set<Set<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>>> possibleWeeks) {
        return possibleWeeks.stream()
                .filter(containsMatchup())   // Finds the weeks to add
                .map(this::addWeek);   // Create new SeasonBuilders with the new week
}
```

You won't need `map`/`flatMap` then, just one `flatMap`:

```
sbStream = sbStream.flatMap(sb -> sb.addWeeks(possibleWeeks));
```

But this won't help your performance much anyway.

Comment: You were correct that collecting and streaming again was not the main performance problem. I ran the it again with your suggestion and it had some minor performance increase